# Django LiveServerTestCase + Nose

Tags: django, unit-testing, selenium, jenkins, nose

I discovered the Django `LiveServerTestCase` recently and use it to run `Selenium` test cases (`python manage.py test`). What I like about it is that it automatically runs a Selenium server in the background.

I'd like to tun the test cases from `Jenkins` and found these [commands](http://www.alexconrad.org/2011/10/jenkins-and-python.html)

```
   nosetests --with-xcoverage --with-xunit --cover-package=myapp --cover-erase
   pylint -f parseable myapp/ | tee pylint.out
```

Unfortunately, they don't run the Django test server while executing the script (and initialise the database, etc).

Is there anything I can do to use `nose` to work with `LiveServerTestCase` the way Django would do it?

Answer (score 0):

Necroposting a response here because this question lead me to some interesting findings.

I have a similar situation to the OP I was able to sort by using [django-nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose)

```
python manage.py test functional_tests access_control --with-coverage --cover-package=access_control --cover-html
```

In this case access_control is the product app and functional_tests is a seperate app with the LiveServerTestCase tests. access_control has standard django unittests.